# iOS App Metadata Rejected: MFi Certification PPID #

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, mfi

My iOS app has been rejected and I got the following message from Apple:

.......

*Reasons for Rejection: MFI Issue*

*We started your review but cannot continue because we cannot locate your MFi Certificate PPID #.*

*Please go to Manage Your Applications in iTunes Connect and edit your metadata to provide the MFi Certificate PPID # in the Review Notes. Once you've added this information, click "Save," then "Submit New Metadata" and we can proceed with your review.*

......

What is an MFi Certificate PPID#? Where/how do I get one for my app?

I submitted the same app (older revisions) three times before but didn't get this kind of message. Why I am getting this now? The last revision I submitted successfully was on Feb. 12, 2012. Has Apple added more requirements since then?

Thanks,
-Teddy

Comment: Is this related? https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Product Plan ID.  You should be able to find this in the MFi portal.  They are asking about the physical accessory your application interfaces with.

Comment: Thanks Jim, that was exactly it. -Teddy

Answer (score 0):

I came here when searching for a solution of my own problem. 
If you are using any kind third party library and hardware accessories in your project, you can get this message.

To avoid this issues, you can remove all the libs that are not necessary to the project. In the info.plist remove External Accessory properties, from the link library build phase remove ExternalAccessor lib.

Or, you can collect the MFiD PPID from the hardware vendor.